# How to convert a column of a dataframe from char to ascii integers? [Pandas]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one columns called 'label' holds values like 'b', 'm', 'n' etc.

I want 'label' to instead hold the ascii equivalent of the letter.
How do I do it?

Comment: Sorry are you asking for the `ord` value of each character?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
In [81]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'label':list('bmn')})
df

Out[81]:
  label
0     b
1     m
2     n

In [82]:    
df['ascii'] = df['label'].apply(ord)
df

Out[82]:
  label  ascii
0     b     98
1     m    109
2     n    110
```

It maybe quicker to do a list comprehension:

```
In [83]:
df['ascii'] = [ord(x) for x in df['label']]
df

Out[83]:
  label  ascii
0     b     98
1     m    109
2     n    110
```

You can also use `map`:

```
In [85]:
df['ascii'] = df['label'].map(ord)
df

Out[85]:
  label  ascii
0     b     98
1     m    109
2     n    110
```

**Timings**

for a small df:

```
In [87]:
%timeit [ord(x) for x in df['label']]
%timeit df['label'].map(ord)
%timeit df['label'].apply(ord)

100000 loops, best of 3: 14 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 µs per loop
```

For a 3K df:

```
In [89]:
%timeit [ord(x) for x in df['label']]
%timeit df['label'].map(ord)
%timeit df['label'].apply(ord)

1000 loops, best of 3: 246 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
```

So here the list comprehension scales better than the other methods

Answer (score 0):

e.g. "a"=97 in ascii}
write print(ord("a"))

> print(ord("a"))

answer would be 97

Comment: This answer is not relevant to `pandas`